# map function not working with class that extends array

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-class

I have a class extending an array

```
class PositionsAndMedia extends Array {
    constructor(x) {
        super(...x.map(x => new MyClass(x)));
    }
}
```

The class constructor receives an array of objects and transforms every object with MyClass

Everything seems to work perfectly, but if I try:

```
positionsAndMediaInTree = new PositionsAndMedia(myArray)
positionsAndMediaInTree.splice(matchingIndex, 1);
```

I get this error in the browser:

```
classes.js:73 Uncaught TypeError: positionsAndMedia.map is not a function
    at new PositionsAndMedia (classes.js:73)
    at PositionsAndMedia.slice (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:34
```

Line 73 is the `super(....)` line in the class definition.

Since `PositionsAndMedia` class extends the Array class, I'd suppose that the `map()` method is available for the `PositionsAndMedia` class.

Why do I get this error? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Your error message doesn't match the code (`positionsAndMedia` vs. `positionsAndMediaInTree`, `slice` vs. `splice`). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message says `slice`, not `splice`, and the error makes sense for `slice` (but not for `splice`).

Your `PositionsAndMedia` constructor assumes that it always gets an array as an argument, but that isn't always true. `slice` creates and returns a new array, and it creates the new array it returns by calling the constructor for the array subclass (`PositionsAndMedia` in your case) without any arguments. Other array methods, such as `map` and `filter`, do that as well.

Array subclass constructors must allow for all of the kinds of arguments that `Array` allows for:

- None at all
- A single number to set length
- A non-number, or more than one argument, to set initial contents

The minimal change to fix it might look something like this:

```
class PositionsAndMedia extends Array {
    constructor(x, ...rest) {
        if (Array.isArray(x)) {
            // You might consider doing something with `rest` here, too,
            // since otherwise any other arguments are ignored
            super(...x.map(x => new MyClass(x)));
        } else {
            // Default behavior
            super(x, ...rest);
        }
    }
}
```